# How to inject a 'register typed' parameter in a constructor

Tags: c#, unity-container

In my quest to Unity knowledge, I want to register a type which as a 'registered type' as constructor parameter.

In my Bootstrapper.cs file I have this configuration :

```
 container.RegisterType<IRepository<User>, UserRepository>();
 container.RegisterType<BaseService<User>, UserService>(); // <-- Should I inject the parameter here ?
 container.RegisterType<IFactory<BaseService<User>>, Factory<UserService>>(); // <-- or here
```

Now this is the implementation of the BaseService class :

```
public abstract class BaseService<TModel> 
{
    private readonly IRepository<TModel> _repository;

    // Injected parameter in constructor
    public BaseService(IRepository<TModel> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
}
```

My question is how to inject in the BaseService constructor the parameter resolved by this line : 
 container.RegisterType, UserRepository>(); ?

I've checked I use the InjectedParameter but I don't know how to use properly in this case.

Thanks,

**EDIT**

here is the other implementation :

UserService :

```
public class UserService : BaseService<User>
{
    public UserService(IRepository<User> repository) : base(repository)
    {
    }
}
```

Factory :

```
public class Factory<T> : IFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public T Create()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want firstly register `IRepository<User>`, secondly resolve it and then register `BaseService<User>` that dependend at `IRepository<User>` from step 2, then `InjectionConstructor` will help you. If you want only register `IRepository<User>` and resolve `BaseService<User>` somewhere else (not in config (Bootstrapper.cs) file) you should use `DependencyOverride` for it. It will more useful if you give a example where and how you want to resolve `BaseService<User>`

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem with your code? From my point of view it should work without modifications. If you let Unity create a `BaseService<User>` object, it creates a `UserService` instance. I would expected that the definition is:

```
public class UserService : BaseService<User>
{
  ...
}
```

Because you have already registered `IRepository<User>`, there should be no problem to resolve/inject an instance of `UserRepository`.

**Update:**
The problem is the new() constraint in the `Factory<T>` class. Unity (and StructureMap, too) are able to use a `Func<>` to resolve registered dependencies. So you can change your `Factory<T>` class:

```
public class Factory<T> : IFactory<T>
{
  private readonly Func<T> _creator;

  public Factory(Func<T> creator)
  {
    if(creator == null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("creator");

    _creator = creator;
  }

  public T Create()
  {
    return _creator();
  }
}
```

Register that generic factory once:

```
container.RegisterType(typeof(IFactory<>), typeof(Factory<>));
```

Comment: I have an error message in VS : 'UserService' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless construtctor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Factory<T>'

Comment: @Florian: OK. I'm using StructureMap as DI container, so maybe we have to do several experiments, because Unity works a little different. First, I suggest to register a new interface, e.g. IService<User> instead of BaseService<User>. That makes more sense, because BaseService<TModel> provides shared implementation details for derived classes, and normally we register contract and implementation during DI bootstraapping. So, derive your UserService from IService<User> and BaseService<User>. It is not necesssary to derive BaseService<TModel> from IService<TModel>, but this depends...

Comment: I have exactly the same error... I really don't understand. Regarding the UserService class definition. there is an empty ctor  :
public UserService(IRepository<User> repository) : base(repository)
{
}

Comment: @Florian: Hmm, the exception tells us, that the constructor must be parameterless, but there is the 'repository' constructor argument. So, thats a problem with the IFactory registration. Have a look, which restrictions exist for the IFactory usage.

Comment: @Florian: Have you used a new() constraint for the Factory?

Comment: Yes I have :

    public class Factory<T> : IFactory<T> where T : new()
    {
        public T Create()
        {
            return new T();
        }
    }

Comment: That was the problem :(